# Action of command button not invoked if I use ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, jsf-2

I have the following problem:

I have a button that should invoke a method, but the page should't get refreshed (I display a [dialog based on bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals) after clicking on the button and it vanishes otherwise). Therefore I use ajax to say that nothing should get rendered after clicking on the button.

I already used applied it before and it worked. But in the recent version of my code the method isn't invoked anymore as long as I use ajax. If I remove the ajax part the method is invoked as it should be, but the page gets refreshed and I don't want that.

**My code:**

```xml
<h:form>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.condition1}">
        <ui:include src="facelet1.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.condition2}">
        <ui:include src="facelet2.xhtml" />
    </ui:fragment>

    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="bean.method">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none"/>
    </h:commandButton>      
<h:form>
```

**Before** I had it like this and it worked:

```xml
<h:form>
    <ui:include src="bean.faceletPath" />

    <h:commandButton value="Save" action="bean.method">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none"/>
    </h:commandButton>      
<h:form>
```

Thanks all,

/metalhamster

---

**Edit:**

facelet1.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

<ui:composition>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Name:">
        <h:inputText value="bean.name">
        <h:outputText value="Value:">
        <h:inputText value="bean.value">
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

facelet2.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

<ui:composition>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Name:">
        <h:inputText value="bean.name">
        <h:outputText value="Text:">
        <h:inputText value="bean.text">
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your facelet1.xhtml and facelet2.xhtml codes.

Comment: Maybe try setting your actions using EL like `action="#{bean.method()}"`

Comment: @dratewka This didn't help